# How to get integer LocationId into ViewModel from ListItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, selectlistitem

In my `form`, I have a `DropDownList` in which I am populating the data from table `Locations` from my `Database`. When the user selects the `LocationName`, the corresponding `LocationId` should get saved into the `ViewModel` so that I can pass it to the `POST` method to save the data into the `Database`. But, instead of getting the corresponding `LocationId`, I am getting `0`.

Upon searching for the cause, I find that as `ListItem` needs the `value` and `text` fields in the form of `string`, while saving the data, I am forced to convert the `LocationId` into `string` using `.ToString()`. How can I get the `LocationId` to be stored into the `ViewModel`?

**Code Snippets:**

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Locate(int Id)
{
    InventoryLocationsHistoryViewModel locationsHistoryVM = new InventoryLocationsHistoryViewModel();

    // Populating Locations DropDownList
    var locationsList = new List<InventoryLocations>();
    locationsList = _context.InventoryLocations.ToList();
    var locations = locationsList.OrderBy(l => l.LocationName).Select(us => new SelectListItem { Value = us.LocationId.ToString(), Text = us.LocationName }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Locations = locations;

    return View(locationsHistoryVM);
}
```

**View**

```
<label asp-for="LocationId" class="fg-labels" for="locationName"></label>
<select asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="ViewBag.Locations" class="chosen disabledropdowncntrl" data-placeholder="Choose a Location" name="locationName" id="dropDownLocationNames">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public int LocationId { get; set; }
public InventoryLocations Location { get; set; }
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form is posted, the parameters are named after `name` values of the inputs. So what is currently posted is `locationName=5`, because you have this in the select:

```
name="locationName"
```

Looks like you need to change this to

```
name="locationId"
```

to match the parameter name in the view model.

And don't worry about string vs int, model binding should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Let me try that.

Comment: It worked. But I want to understand why it worked. The ViewModel has LocationId (with an uppercase L), but the name in the DropDownList has locationId with a lowercase L). How can both be the same?

Comment: @ShashankKuchibhotla, HTTP query parameter names are supposed to be case insensitive.

Comment: Under no circumstances do you ever attempt to change the `name` attribute when using TagHelpers - they will always generate the correct `name` attribute for 2-way model binding. The `name`attribute should be removed altogether.